# Can we find constant $C>0$ so that $\lfloor x \rfloor \geq C x$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inequality

We know that [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) $\lfloor x \rfloor \leq x$ for $x\in \mathbb R$.

> Can we say that $\lfloor x \rfloor \gtrsim x$ for $x>1$?  Can we find constant $C>0$ so that $\lfloor x \rfloor \geq C x$?

Comment: Is the range over which the last relation is supposed to be valid only $x>1$?

Comment: If $x$ is restricted to be at least $1$, then $C=\frac12$ suffices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $C=\dfrac12$ works. Note that 
$$\dfrac{x-1}{x}>\dfrac12\\
\iff2x-2>x\\
\iff x>2$$
Also,
$$\dfrac 1x>\dfrac12\iff x<2$$
Hence,
$$\boxed{\dfrac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x}>\dfrac 12}\ \ \forall x>1$$

Answer (score 1):

If we restric the domain to $x\geq1$, then clearly $C=\frac{1}{2}$ can be a solution. But, more generally, all $C$ such that $$0<C\leq \frac{1}{2}$$ are correct.

You can also see this graph:

[image]